# See dynamicly generated DOM and CSS

Tags: html, css, dom, runtime

[This address](http://www.meetatrandom.com/main/console) is has a console javascript that i build with a custom
jquery plugin. I wan't to extract the exact DOM and CSS after i fill some
commands into it. Since the CSS and the DOM is generated at Runtime, i'm
unable to get it.

So my question is, how can i see this DOM and CSS that is generated at runtime?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Firefox, use [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/).

If using IE, use the dev tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>).

With these and other browsers, you can also use [firebuglite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite).

These all expose the DOM/CSS *after* it has been manipulated, as it is in the browser.

Comment: Chrome also has Inspect Element/Inspector/Developer Tools.

Comment: Firebug is the best tool for Firefox, there is also a jQuery plugin for Firebug so it can inspect jQuery too - FireQuery.